when i am sending some data using post request in django and test it in postman it shows no error but in browser it is not responding correctly
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST': 
    name = request.POST['name']   #in this way we are collecting data
    email= request.Post['email']
    password = request.Post['password']

    print(f'Name :{name}')         #in this way we are printing the data
    print(f'Email :{email}')
    print(f'Password :{password}')

    return HttpResponse('<h1> This is a post Request</h1>')
elif request.method == 'GET':
    return HttpResponse('<h1> This is a get Request</h1>')
else:
    return HttpResponse('<h1> This is an invalid Request</h1>')

While testing in postman using post request it is showing it is a post request. But in browser it shows this is a get request why is it neglating post request

You don’t have enough information here for someone to help you.

When something is typed into a browser's address bar, it will almost always result in a GET request.
Thats the reason the url you paste in browser generate GET Response. If you want to submit the post request, make a html form and submit it as post.
